# jQuery move div in coordination on scroll

Tags: jquery

I have a table with a fixed header: http://dev.driz.co.uk/table/

What I want to do is when the user scrolls .uiGridContent it will move the .uiGridHeader in accordance so if I scrolled right 50px then the header would move left 50px so that the grids still match up.

How would I do this with jQuery?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the Scroll event and the scrollLeft getter/setter

```
$('.uiGridContent').scroll(function() {
    $('.uiGridHeader').scrollLeft($('.uiGridContent').scrollLeft());
});
```

[example here](http://jsfiddle.net/CCMKu/5/)

tip:

change the padding-left of the header into margin-left to eliminate the error on the end of the scrolling

```
div.uiGridHeader
{
    height: 28px;
    margin-right: 17px;
    border: #ccc 1px solid;
    border-width: 0 0 1px 0;
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(#fff,#ddd);
    border-radius: 3px 3px 0 0;
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

[example 2 here](http://jsfiddle.net/CCMKu/6/)

Answer (score 0):

This can be resolved using CSS. Try `position:fixed` property for your div.

If you are using jQuery - you may want to use the `.scroll` [property](http://api.jquery.com/scroll/) for your calculations.

Comment: It can't! Please see: http://www.tablefixedheader.com/demonstration/ for an example of what I am trying to replicate. I've seen in their JS file they do something with the margin of the header on scroll although the updated dimensions don't show in the DOM :/

Answer (score 0):

Could you try with some JQuery plugin that manages fixed header? See as an example http://www.datatables.net/release-datatables/extras/FixedHeader/html_table.html.